# My random number generator keeps changing when my function runs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random, user-input

So Basically what im suppose to be doing is letting the user try and guess the random number, And what is happening at the moment is that my random number keeps changing when I click the **Guess** button. I have included the **random number** to show next to my **higher** or **lower**  so I can prove that it keeps changing:

Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Guess a Number</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="guess">Text Input:</label>
      <input type="text" name="guess" id="guess" value=""  />
    </div>  
    <p id="highlow"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Guess" onClick="guessing()" />
    <p id="correct"></p>
    <p id="timesGuessed".</p>
    <p id="showGuessed"></p>
    <input id="show"type="submit" value="Show The Number" onClick=""/>
    <p id="showNumber"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Get New Number" onClick=""/>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
function guessing() {

  var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var round = Math.round(random) ;
  var number = round;
  var guess = document.getElementById('guess').value;
  var guessed = '';

  if(guess < number) {
    document.getElementById('highlow').innerHTML = "Higher" + number;
  } 
  else if (guess > number) {
    document.getElementById('highlow').innerHTML = "Lower";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('correct').innerHTML = "Correct, The number was: " + number;
  } 

  document.getElementById('show').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('showNumber').innerHTML = "The number was: " + number;  
  };

  guessed += guess ;
  document.getElementById('showGuessed').innerHTML += "  " + guess + "  ";
}
```

Just a summary of what I'm trying to do, for a project I need to allow the user to input a number to try and guess the **random number**, I have used if statements to tell the user whether to guess **Higher or Lower**, But at the moment my random number keeps changing! There is a **Get new Number** button which is suppose to give the user a new number. But for now I'm focusing on getting the random number correct

Comment: You're greating `var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);` every time `guessing()` is called. It looks like you should do that on page load.

Comment: Your getting a new random number because that's the first thing you do in your function. You should get the random number outside of the guessing function and add it through a parameter.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? The question is clear and the relevant code is in the question.

Comment: @Popnoodles Thank you, I am just a beginner at this and it's always good to learn from other people :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is first create a random number and save it in some variable when the page loads and in your guessing() function do not create a random number there just use the number generated earlier and check with the user entered number and process as you may require.

And change that stored number when user clicks  Get New Number button.

Comment: @Popnoodles I created an answer: I tested it before of course... It works :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating `var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);` every time `guessing()` is called. You need to assign the number on page load. Assigning it outside of the function will make it accessible inside your functions.

```
var number; // declare in global scope
refreshNumber();

// refresh number
function refreshNumber()
{
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    number = Math.round(random) ;
}

// called every time a guess is made
function guessing()
{
    // remove these three lines
    // var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    // var round = Math.round(random) ;
    // var number = round;
    // leave the rest
    var guess = document.getElementById('guess').value;
    ....
```

To make your Get New Number button work, I added the function refreshNumber which needs calling on click `<input type="submit" value="Get New Number" onClick="refreshNumber()"/>`. You should reuse that function to set the number on page load (see the updated code).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ow7Lvz3s/

Comment: Thank you @Popnoodles I was wondering how I can create a new random number? I tried doing :

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate a new number without reloading the page? Also is that submit button just there not in a form, because if it's in a form your page will reload.

Comment: Ah you have a get new number button. You need another function. I created it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ow7Lvz3s/ though you could easily just have the button reload the page

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Thank you for that @Yamu. I just added the random number outside the function :).

```
random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
round = Math.round(random) ;
number = round;
function guessing()
{


var guess = document.getElementById('guess').value;
var guessed = '';

    if(guess < number)
    {
        document.getElementById('highlow').innerHTML = "Higher" + number;
    }
    else if (guess > number)
    {
        document.getElementById('highlow').innerHTML = "Lower";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('correct').innerHTML = "Correct, The number was: " + number;
    }   

        document.getElementById('show').onclick = function()
        {
            document.getElementById('showNumber').innerHTML = "The number was: " + number;  
        };


    guessed += guess ;
    document.getElementById('showGuessed').innerHTML += "  " + guess + "  ";

}
```